# Dragging and dropping

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop the table contents into a text-box.

**HTML :**

```
<table id = "carTypes">
    <tr><th>Car Type</th><th>Price per mile</th></tr>
    <tr><td carValue = "compact" draggable = "true" >Compact</td><td>$0.99</td></tr>
    <tr><td carValue = "Intermediate" draggable = "true" >Intermediate</td><td>$1.99</td></tr>
    <tr><td carValue = "Luxury" draggable = "true" >Luxury</td><td>$2.99</td></tr>
    <tr><td carValue = "Limo" draggable = "true" >Limo</td><td>$4.99</td></tr>
</table><p>Drag and Drop from the above car-types list to below box: <input type = "text" id = "carTypeChosen" placeholder = 'car type you want' /></p>
```

**JS :**

```
var registerDragDrop = function() {
    var dragSource = document.getElementById("carTypes");

    dragSource.ondragstart = function(event) {
        var dataToCopy = this.getElementsByTagName("td").getAttribute("carValue");
        event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", dataToCopy);
        return true;
    };

    var dropTarget = document.getElementById("carTypeChosen");

    dropTarget.ondrop = function(event) {
        this.value = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };

    dropTarget.ondragover = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };

    dropTarget.ondragend = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
};
```

When I'm dragging and dropping the car type, null value is being dropped instead of a car value.I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please explain

Comment: Please post the rest of HTML code `carTypeChosen` is undefined.

Comment: when I drag and drop from the list of car types, null is being placed in the input field instead of a value.

Comment: Thank you. Let me what am I doing wrong and what should be the approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7rf4sz7/1/)**

Your code work after some changes, you have `this` inside `dragSource.ondragstart` function that return all table instead of dropped `td`  what means when you try `getAttribute("carValue")` that generate an error because table don't have a `carValue` attribut, so use `event.target` that return target or dropped td in our case instead of `this`.

Also you have to call your function `registerDragDrop()` after definition.

**JS changes**

**Replace :**

```
this.getElementsByTagName("td").getAttribute("carValue");
```

By :

```
var dataToCopy = event.target.getAttribute("carValue");
```

**Full JS :**

```
var registerDragDrop = function() {
    var dragSource = document.getElementById("carTypes");

    dragSource.ondragstart = function(event) {
        var dataToCopy = event.target.getAttribute("carValue");
        event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", dataToCopy);
        return true;
    };

    var dropTarget = document.getElementById("carTypeChosen");

    dropTarget.ondrop = function(event) {
        this.value = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };

    dropTarget.ondragover = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };

    dropTarget.ondragend = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
};
```

Hope this help.